# System.LimitException: Too many async calls created: 2

Tags: apex, batch, asyncapexjob, summer-16

I am trying to run two batches:

1.ContactNonEligibleMarker - Updates a status on the contact

2.RelationshipCreatorForContact - Creates child records(`Relationship__c`) under a contact.

In the finish method of an another batch(Main batch),it was working fine until **Spring 16**.

Recently Sandbox was upgraded to **Summer 16** the above is not working am getting below error on the line where the second batch's execute is present .

> System.LimitException: Too many async calls created: 2

As a workaround i serialized(one after the other) the batch call ,which works without any issues.

I looked at the Release notes of **Summer 16** couldn't find any information about the above issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is a known issue with Summer '16, and they say they have a fix scheduled for Summer '16 Patch 6.0. I wasn't able to find an ETA for the patch.
Here is the issue on the Success Community: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000017ysTQAQ

Answer (score 5):

We ran into this issue with Summer 16 and have opened a ticket with Salesforce. They acknowledge the issue is happening due to release and their R&D team is working on it.

I'm going to ask whether my sandbox can be rolled back until they fix it, which will hopefully be soon.  No idea whether they can do that, though.